# Source Class and Target class extending same class mapstruct

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

```
abstract class baseClass {
 String updateUser;
}

class A extends baseClass {
 String updateTime;
}

class B extnds baseClass {
  String updateTime;
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface FLGenericMapper {
  B mapToB(A a);
}
```

I have similar code. when mapping is done from A to B.
I see that the updateUser is not mapping.
Please some one let me know, Is there anything I should be doing to map the updateUser of abstract class.

Comment: Could you share the generated code? Are you using field mapping, or bean mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly the problem is. Do you use lombok? Do you use field mapping?

If you use field mapping your fields should be public (otherwise nobody can access them). If you make them public it works for me. Here's the code as I think it should be:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MyMapper {

    B mapToB(A a);

    abstract class BaseClass {
        public String updateUser;
    }

    class A extends BaseClass {
        public String updateTime;
    }

    class B extends BaseClass {
        public String updateTime;
    }

}
```

Result:

```java
@Component
public class MyMapperImpl implements MyMapper {

    @Override
    public B mapToB(A a) {
        if ( a == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        B b = new B();

        b.updateUser = a.updateUser;
        b.updateTime = a.updateTime;

        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thanks.